# Syntax Error with FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

EXTREME noob, here. Just started learning SQL about a week ago and working through the basics.
Anyway, I'm using Microsoft Access 2010 right now and just found out how to run SQL queries on it (was using DB Browser before). But now I've run into a bit of a pickle.

I have several tables; Orders, Products, Customers, and SalesReps (my own little test project) and I'm trying to display the Orders up but I want to join the results from the Products table so I can, eventually, total up the cost for each order and work out the profit. Anyway, one step at a time.

Here's my issue:

```
SELECT Products.SKU
FROM [Products]
JOIN [Orders];
```

That's my query right now. Really basic. But, for some reason, I keep getting the 'Syntax Error with FROM clause' and I'm not sure why. I tried removing the JOIN command and it works perfectly. I've even reversed the order so I'm joining the Products table onto the Orders table, AND I've tried using INNER/OUTER JOIN as well but the problem remains the same. It's probably something extremely stupid so I apologize in advance...

Any tips? Again, I'm an extreme noob here so please bear that in mind when you're writing your answers. Thanks!

Just FYI, this is probably the most 'advanced' thing I know right now; how to join tables. Just to give you an idea on where my knowledge extends to.

Also update on my dilemma. I dropped SQL for a bit, bit going on, and just came back to it now.

Here is my new query:

```
SELECT Orders.Product, Orders.Quantity
FROM Orders
JOIN Products
ON Orders.Product = Products.SKU;
```

and I'm still getting the Syntax error in FROM clause error.

Still not seeing the error.

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify which fields should JOIN the two tables into "one" e.g. `SELECT Products.SKU, Orders.CUSTOMER FROM Products JOIN Orders ON Orders.SKU = Products.SKU;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a join predicate in the [Join clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), otherwise it has no idea how you want to assemble the joined data

```
SELECT Products.SKU
FROM Products
JOIN Orders on Orders.<field> = Products.<field>
```

Comment: I think that was one of the first things I did, but I was stupid and thought I could dumb it down a bit hence why there isn't the condition. Anyway, tried it again and I get the same error.
SELECT Products.SKU
FROM [Products]
JOIN [Orders]
ON Products.SKU=Orders=Product;

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a JOIN condition:

```
Select products.sku
From products
Join orders 
On products.somecolumn = orders.columnThatHasTheSameDataAsProductsDotColumn
```